# What am I doing wrong for this submenu to not appear?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, so please bear with me. I'm trying to make my submenu appear on hover. The second set of `<ul>` is for submenu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.menu.li').hover(
        function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
        function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
});

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a><li>
<ul>
<li>Hi</li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. You need to reference the parent UL by ID, not *class*:

```
$('#menu li').hover(...
```

moreover, if you are addressing LIs within the UL, you want to use either [ancestor-descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) or [parent > child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('#menu li') // ancestor descendant
$('#menu > li') // parent > child
```

Additionally, there is no point in setting the CSS display property, when you can just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li').hover(
        function() { $('ul', this).show(); },
        function() { $('ul', this).hide(); });
});
```

Comment: <3 Are there any tips and suggestions for me too?

Comment: The `function() { $(this).show() }, function() { $(this).hide() });` isn't working. It's not selecting the second `<ul>`. It's just showing and hiding #menu li

Comment: @Doug - sorry, fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things here, first the selector should be `ul#menu li` since `menu` is the `id` not the `class` (class selectors use `.class`).  Also a space in there, otherwise it's looking for a `<ul>` with a `class="menu li"` to match.

Then, your `<ul>` needs to be a child of the `<li>` not a sibling, like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>​
```

Lastly, you can add a bit of flair as well, like this:

```
$('ul#menu li').hover(function() { 
    $('ul', this).slideDown(); 
}, function() {
    $('ul', this).slideUp(); 
});​
```

This creates a sliding effect as well [that you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/k8eWz/1/)

Comment: It's so much cleaner if it were to be a sibling. Should I change my jQuery to accommodate that?

Comment: @Doug - Nope, it's invalid HTML if you try, and the results won't be predictable once you break the rules :)

Comment: @Nick - `ul#menu` is actually marginally slower than just `#menu`. (fun nitpick :)

Comment: @karim - But if you have `div#menu` on another page... :) I tend not to change that, since I've seen users with that case more than a few times, even if I do think they're nuts ;)

Comment: I see. Now I'm testing with divs, and don't understand why is it failing. Let me update my question